# Can't connect to Firebase at existing Android Studio Project

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I've opened existing Firebase project, but i'm receiving error in Runtime.

```
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.dji.GSDemo.GoogleMap. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

I've tried to "Connect to Firebase" using the Firebase Assistant, but getting:

```
Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.
```

I've tried updating stuff at SDK-Tools:
[image: sdk]

But it's all up to date like another firebase project of mine that works.

My problem is caused because i've added Firebase Activities to existing non-firebase project.

This is my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {

    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
    }

    applicationId "com.dji.GSDemo.GoogleMap"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    //Enabling multidex support
    multiDexEnabled true //Mention in the doc

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

//Mention in the doc
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}

packagingOptions{
    doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
}
}
dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
compile 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'


compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

compile ('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.4.1')
provided ('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.4.1')
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887880/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first)

Comment: Hi @PeterHaddad thanks, I've tried your solution and it didn't solve my problem

This is my application in the manifest:
<application
        android:name=".MApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

And i've added in public class MApplication extends Application :
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        fpvDemoApplication.onCreate();
    }

Comment: did you create a new class  and extend `Application class`?

Comment: Yes, i've also tried creating new application in the manifest, and then new class with only onCreate, but then all of the manifest didn't compile

Comment: @PeterHaddad if I open 
    <application android:name="MyApplication"></application>
Then the rest of my Manifest file won't compile

Where  am I suppose to close it ? 

I alreay have <application
        android:name=".MApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
And class
public class MApplication extends Application {

Which extends it, Tried to FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) there but it didn't work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165961/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-johnsnowthedeveloper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the link in the comment for this problem:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.dji.GSDemo.GoogleMap. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

For the second problem please update the firebaseui:

change this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

[FirebaseUI compatibility](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies)

Comment: As I commented above, I've tried your solution of FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) and it's not solving my problem.

and what is the 'second problem' you're talking about sir? I have one problem here

In normal projects i'm able to Connect to Firebase, and then I don't have the error in runtime. 

I just need to solve the connection to Firebase

Comment: You are right, I see I have some compling issues in different place, thanks, trying to solve it